# Sending mouse coordinates to a d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a d3 chart that I would like to send mouse coordinates to from another chart,

I trigger the mouse event remotely on the target chart.  It all works great until there.  The problem is getting the mouse coordinates in the code below.

```
$chart.on('mousemove', function () {
         var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
```

Mouse values are always NaN.  I suspect because the mouse is over another container.  Is there a way to get those mouse values here?

Comment: what if you log d3.event, what do you get here ?

Comment: how does that work?  just console d3.event()?

Comment: Just console.log d3.event, and you should get a number of points

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete example of your problem (including both charts) so that other users can attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks @thatOneGuy!

Answer (score 0):

So the idea turned out to be actually "how to trigger an event of one container from another."

1. Container - Trigger

Create a custom jquery func - jquery works well as it's the easiest way to select an html element.

```
$.fn.triggerSVGEvent = function(eventName, extraParameter) {
           var event = document.createEvent('SVGEvents');
           event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
           event.extraParameter = extraParameter;  //this can be extended how you like
           this[0].dispatchEvent(event);
           return $(this);
         };
```

Then from where you want to trigger the event,

```
var $el = $('#chart-two');
$el.triggerSVGEvent('mousemove', mouse); 
//I am sending out mouse coordinates as that was my main challenge.
```

2. Container - Receiver

   var $el = $('#chart-two');
   $el.on('mousemove', function() {
     var mouse = d3.event.extraParameter;
   }

Big thanks to @thatOneGuy